# How to get Query Plan Reuse in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan, sp-executesql

I inherited a database application that has a table with about 450 queries.    There's a calling procedures takes the `@QueryId` and `@TheId` as input parameters. The only way these queries are executed is via this procedure. The queries are like this:

```
@sql = replace('insert into #temp select col1, col2, col3, col4
from SomeTable st join OtherTable ot on matching_column
where st.TheID = ##TheId##', '##TheId##', @TheId);

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

I want to get plan reuse, so I replace `##TheId##` with `@TheId` and then execute the query like this:

```
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@TheId int', @TheId;
```

However, I'm still seeing the same behavior where each plan is a unique plan, even though the `@sql` string is already compiled and in the procedure cache.

Now the string is like this

```
...where where st.TheID = @TheId
```

Question: how can I get plan reuse as desired on a parameterized query?

Comment: That is NOT a parameterized query. You have completely defeated the parameters here by building up a string. You should pass your parameter to the dynamic sql, or even better just avoid dynamic sql. From what you posted there is no need for dynamic sql here at all.

Comment: *Don't* use dynamic SQL. This isn't a parameterized query, it's just a plain-old string, vulnerable to SQL injection just like any other SQL string

Comment: This is a good approach as it (*even more importantly*) addresses the SQL Injection issues.

Comment: I'm trying to fix procedure cache bloat.  There are 450 different rules, but they're executed thousands of times per day for various records.  I looked in production last night and saw 50,000+ distinct plans.  I want to reduce this to ~450.  Then I can tune the bad performers, see which are most expensive, etc.  I cannot do that with 50,000 queries

Comment: Is the sql text exactly the same for each of those different plans?

Comment: Is #temp the same table between the calls, or does it get dropped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you modify it to the following you should get plan reuse as this will make it a parameterized query:

```
@sql = replace('insert into #temp select col1, col2, col3, col4
from SomeTable st join OtherTable ot on matching_column
where st.TheID = ##TheId##', '##TheId##', '@TheId');

exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@TheID INT', @TheID;
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175580(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Yikes, so it is.  I would imagine the problem may be around that #temp table.  You may want to look and see if you are getting a new recompile when you run that query by capturing the XE for sql_statement_recompile.  I believe the insert into is causing a recompile.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!  I should have figured out that it was the #temp table messing me up!  The solution is to remove the "insert into #temp" from the Query as well. Then I reworked the execution to this:

`insert #temp exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@id int', @id'`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try creating stored procedure without making use of the dynamic query?

Try something along the following lines:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertdata 
(
    @TheId INT -- or whatever data type is being used
)   
AS
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO #temp 
    SELECT 
        col1
        , col2
        , col3
        , col4
    FROM SomeTable st 
    JOIN OtherTable ot ON matching_column
    WHERE st.TheID = @Theid;
END
```

When you want to execute it, you'll simply do:

```
EXEC insertdata 123;
```

Comment: There's no need to use stored procedures. A simple parameterized query is enough

Comment: Thanks, I though about that... but creating 450+ procedures is a tougher road than I wanted to tackle.  I'd love to rewrite this, but there's no appetite to fix what really isn't broken.